# UBUNTTU 19.04 Not Shuting down

Tags: shutdown, 19.04

I upgraded my Lenovo laptop from UBUNTU 18.04 to 19.04 and now it freezes at a blinking cursor mode after shutting down. I can shut down my laptop only by holding power key few seconds. I followed some instructions proposed for UBUNTU 18.04 but they didn't work here. Please help me if you can.

Answer (score 0):

You can investigate an issue by reading systemd-logs:

```
journalctl --since today
```

Please, find the shutdown logs and put here.